# is it appropriate to use Reflection in this example

Tags: java, reflection, static-variables

I am asking your opinion on this matter because I am not sure I should be using reflection in this scenario.

The scenario is that I have a table that I need to find out whether is on a dirty state or not. If a user makes changes into the table and then navigates away into another page without saving the changes... a warning message should pop up saying "Unsaved changes will be lost".

The approach I am using is to create a flag that is set to true if the table is dirty and false otherwise. When the user navigates away, without saving the table, by clicking on a link (a link that takes him to another site) the warning message pops up. On the other hand, if the user saves the table before navigating away then no warning message appears.

Issues that might occur if I make the dirty flag static is that another user can encounter the flag in a state that it shouldn't be. Since the static variable is bound to the class, every time I check this variable, the value of this field will be shared across every user in the application, isn't it?

On the other hand, however, if I don't make it static and use it as a member variable then, when I instantiate the object through reflection, it is going to return the default values. False if Boolean, null if String and or which ever value is initialized as.

This leads me to the conclusion that Reflection is not the best option to use in this example ?

I look forward to hearing from you, your opinion/view is very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your table will be backed by a TableModel. The instance of your TableModel that displays the page of data to your user and allows the user to edit data inside that model, should "know" if it's in a saved state or not.

That can be simply be done by creating a custom table model and adding a dirty flag - that's triggered every time `setValueAt` is called:

```
public class DirtyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

  protected boolean dirty;

  public boolean isDirty() {
    return dirty;
  }
  /**
   * Called with setDirty(false) after save
  */
  public void setDirty(boolean on) {
    dirty = on;
  }
  @Override
  public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
    setDirty(true);
    super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
  }

}
```

No need for reflection of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for this flag to be `static`. Making it `static` implies that it's a property of the **class**, not a specific **instance**. In other words, that would be saying that **all** the `MyTable` instances are either dirty or not, which doesn't make any sense. You should have this flag as an instance variable, and initialize it in the constructor (or inline, which is just syntactic sugaring over placing the the initialization in the constructor). Whether or not you use reflection to initialize the table instances seems inconsequential to this question.